# Mysql SELECT get all columns in the table based on one WHERE condition

Tags: mysql

I would like to get `tokens` based on one `WHERE` condition. E.g if i would like to `SELECT` `Gregor` and if we look into `committee` it should retrive then the token for `Liza, Matt`

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO users (name)
VALUES ("Gregor"),
    ("Liza"),
    ("Matt"),
    ("Bob");
    
CREATE TABLE committee(
    user_id INT,
    friend_id INT,
    member_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`, `friend_id`, `member_id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`friend_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`member_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
);
INSERT INTO committee (user_id, friend_id, member_id)
VALUES (1, 2, 3),
(1, 2, 4);

CREATE TABLE tokens(
    user_id INT,
    token VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO tokens (user_id, token)
VALUES (1, "lclasld2"),
    (2, "xxkakdasd"),
    (3, "123kdkfs"),
    (4, "hjj32");
```

Current query i got:

```
SELECT token FROM tokens WHERE user_id = 1;
```

How it behave now:

```
user_id, token
1, lclasld2
```

What i expect, when i run the query:

```
user_id, token
2, xxkakdasd
3, 123kdkfs
4, hjj32
```

Comment: Your expected output looks like it includes the token for the user "Bob". Is that actually expected?
Are you trying to get Gregors token, along with all of this freinds tokens?

Comment: Yes, since Bob is included in the second row of the `committee` But if try to get the token for Matt, then it should only include Gregor, Liza

Comment: So you are trying to find all of the tokens for users in the same committee?

Comment: Yes, that is precisely what i want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can union the select friend _id and member_id for user_id 1

> ```
> SELECT
> user_id, token
> FROM tokens 
> WHERE user_id IN (SELECT friend_id FROM committee WHERE user_id = 1 
>                  UNION SELECT member_id FROM committee WHERE user_id = 1)
> ```
>
> ```
> user_id | token    
> ------: | :--------
>       2 | xxkakdasd
>       3 | 123kdkfs 
>       4 | hjj32
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=77d9445f7ed55ea44698b20c08c0c451)*

Comment: Thank you! Never thougt about unions

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to insert all of values in one line, trying adding an insert for each individual object like so: `INSERT INTO TOKENS() VALUES();  INSERT INTO TOKENS() VALUES()`, so on and so forth.